# Auto scroll with data updates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

So I'm trying to make an info screen for a local company in my neighborhood. They want a page, that automatically scrolls to the bottom, then gets back to the top and reloads the data from some outlook calendars. I'm using ASP.net to do so, but I can't seem to figure out how to use javascript (jQuery) to make something automatically scroll to the bottom of the page and then back to the top to then reload the data.

That's where you guys come into the picture, I could really use some help here!
Just for knowledge, I'm not the best at javascript, so if you could explain what's happening in your answer, that would be lovely!

Regards.

Comment: use **scroll** event/function of jquery for scrolling
**ie: $('body').scrollTo(500);**

Comment: Do you have en example of this, where it automatically scrolls to the bottom and then reloads the data @GhanshyamBaravaliya ?

Comment: how your page automatically scroll can you explain @Boog

Comment: Well that's what I need. I need some sort of jquery that automatically scrolls to the bottom of the page and then reloads the content of a div. @GhanshyamBaravaliya

Comment: try this to automatically sroll down page 

$(window).load(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("bottom!");
       // getData();
   }
});;
});

Comment: @GhanshyamBaravaliya that doesn't seem to work.. I've tested it in a jfiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/3tk33tez/ ). I need one that automatically scrolls to the bottom, clears the content of a div, reload the content and then automatically scrolls to the bottom.